# Acciones del metodo main

Tags: poo, clase, parametros

tengo unos problemas con mi tarea de programación orientado a objetos, tengo un ejercicio en el que me solicitan hacer una clase de nombre Empleado la cual ya hice, en esta parte no tengo dudas, si no más bien en la siguiente instrucción, pero por si ayuda a resolver mi duda la dejo por aquí:

```
public class Empleado {
    
    String nombre;
    float sueldo;
    
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre= nombre;
    }
    
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    
    public void setSueldo (float sueldo){
        this.sueldo= sueldo;
    }
    
    public float getSueldo(){
        return sueldo;
    }
    
    public float calcCuotaInfonavit(){
        float cuota;
        cuota=(float) (0.04*sueldo);
        
        return cuota;
        
    }
}
```

Luego, la instrucción dice así:
Así mismo, diseña una clase de prueba denominada Administrador, que realice lo siguiente, por medio del método main( ):

1. Crear un objeto de la clase Empleado.
2. Leer el nombre del empleado.
3. Leer el sueldo del empleado.
4. Asignar el nombre del empleado.
5. Asignar el sueldo del empleado.
6. Determinar la cuota de INFONAVIT del empleado.
7. Mostrar el nombre del empleado.
8. Mostrar el sueldo del empleado.
9. Mostrar la cuota de INFONAVIT del empleado.

Mi clase Administrador la llamé Admin y es esta de aqui:

```
public class Admin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here  
        Scanner tec = new Scanner (System.in);
        Empleado employee= new Empleado();
        Empleado sueldoo= new Empleado();
        Empleado calcCuota= new Empleado();
        
        System.out.println("¿Cuál es su nombre");
        String nombre = tec.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Indique su sueldo");
        float sueldo = tec.nextFloat();
                        
        employee.setNombre(nombre);   
    }   
}
```

Esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento, del punto 1 hasta el 3 pero tengo dudas con el numero 4 que dice Determinar la cuota de Infonavit del empleado, ya intenté escribir la variable cuota como parámetro en el metodo calcCuotaInfonavit dentro de la clase Admin, tal vez no estoy entendiendo bien el problema pero no se a donde mas recurrir, espero puedan ayudarme a despejar mis dudas con la instrucción y si tengo algún error me lo hagan saber, de antemano gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español.
exactamente que es lo que no entiendes de `calcCuotaInfonavit`, que problema presentas, por que cuando dices "_ya intenté escribir la variable cuota como parámetro_" no indicas por que lo intentaste o si te regresa algún error.

Comment: Si mira te explico, en la parte del codigo que dice "employee.setNombre", pues dentro de los parametros quiero asignar las variables de nombre, sueldo y cuota, esto para cumplir con los puntos 4,5,6 de la instruccion que puse más arriba,  al menos asi es como se me ocurre asignar esos variables, si estoy en lo correcto entonces tal vez quedaría algo como "employee.setNombre(nombre, sueldo, cuota);" pero claramente me da error

Comment: @ArielFigueroa tu código es casi correcto, el ejercicio debe ser sencillo simplemente debes saber que en la POO puedes crear un objeto, modificar sus propiedades y obtenerlas, no necesitas crear en este caso varias instancias de Empleado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De lo que presentas hay varios aspectos que me gustaría aclararte para que entendieras bien el concepto de las clases en Java, sus atributos, constructores, getter y setter.

La Clase Empleado en prinicio veo que la tienes bien definida sin embargo, sus atributos nombre y sueldo tiene asignados el modificador de package o default. Esto quiere decir que podrías acceder directamente a dichos atributos desde una clase que estuviera dentro del mismo paquete de Empleado. Normalmente los atributos se suelen encapsular, esto quiere decir, poner privados, y cuando son privados se hace uso de los métodos getNombre para leer el atributo desde fuera de la clase y setNombre para asignarle un valor.

Te lo voy a mostrar en código:

```
package empleado;


public class Empleado {
    
    // Declaro las propiedades de empleado private es decir encapsuladas 
    private String nombre;
    private float sueldo;
    
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre= nombre;
    }
    
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    
    public void setSueldo (float sueldo){
        this.sueldo= sueldo;
    }
    
    public float getSueldo(){
        return sueldo;
    }
    
    public float calcCuotaInfonavit(){
        float cuota;
        cuota=(float) (0.04*sueldo);
        
        return cuota;
        
    }
}
```

Ahora nos vamos al programa principal para hacer las operaciones solicitadas. En el caso que muestras hay algún aspecto que está mal, te comento. Esto que haces a continuación no tiene sentido:

```
 Empleado employee= new Empleado();
 Empleado sueldoo= new Empleado();
 Empleado calcCuota= new Empleado();
```

¿Por qué? te preguntaras, porque sueldo y calcCuota no son objetos de tipo Empleado, sino atributos del Objeto, por lo que no es correcto hacer eso, sería de la siguiente forma. Te añado el código con comentarios:

```
package admin;

import empleado.Empleado; // Me importo la Clase para poder hacer uso de ella

public class Admin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // 1. Crear un objeto Empleado
        Empleado empl1 = new Empleado();
        /* 2. Leer el nombre del Empleado
        Inicialmente en el momento de instanciarlo haciendo uso del Constructor
        vacío Empleado(), sus atributos nombre y y sueldo no tiene ningún valor
        asignado, por lo que estarán vacíos.
         */
        System.out.println("nombre = " + empl1.getNombre());
        System.out.println("sueldo = " + empl1.getSueldo());

    }
}
```

Si ejecutas eso verás que obtienes lo valores por defecto, ya que todavía no les has asigando ningún valor tu:

```
nombre = null
sueldo = 0.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Lo cual tiene sentido. Seguimos completando el programa principal para ver el resto de casos, te incluyo igual comentarios en cada línea para que no tengas dudas de lo que voy haciendo:

```
package admin;

import empleado.Empleado; // Me importo la Clase para poder hacer uso de ella
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Admin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner tec = new Scanner(System.in);
        var cuota = 0.0;
        
        // 1. Crear un objeto Empleado
        Empleado employee = new Empleado();
        
        /* 2 y 4. Leer el nombre y el sueldo del Empleado
        Inicialmente en el momento de instanciarlo haciendo uso del Constructor
        vacío Empleado(), sus atributos nombre y y sueldo no tiene ningún valor
        asignado, por lo que estarán vacíos.
         */
        System.out.println("nombre = " + employee.getNombre());
        System.out.println("sueldo = " + employee.getSueldo());
        
        // 4. Asignar el nombre al empleado
        System.out.println("¿Cuál es su nombre?");
        // si haces uso de Scanner tienes que importarlo y declarar tec como Scanner
        String nombre = tec.nextLine();
        // y ahora asignamos el valor haciendo uso de setNombre
        employee.setNombre(nombre);
        
        // 5. Asignar el sueldo al empleado
        System.out.println("¿Cuál es su sueldo?"); // Mensaje para solicitar el sueldo
        // Parseamos el String a un double para que corresponda con el tipo del sueldo
        float sueldo = Float.parseFloat(tec.nextLine()); 
        employee.setSueldo(sueldo); // seteamos el sueldo al empleado                
        
        /* 6. Calculamos la cuota INFONAVIT del empleado.
         Para ello haremos uso del método de Empleado calcCuotaInfonavit
        que calcula la cuota en base al sueldo asignado al empleado
        y lo guardamos en una variable para mostrarlo posteriormente
        */
        cuota = employee.calcCuotaInfonavit();
        
        // 7,8 y 9. Mostramos nombre, sueldo y la cuota, ya con los valores asignados
        System.out.println("nombre = " + employee.getNombre());
        System.out.println("sueldo = " + employee.getSueldo());
        System.out.println("cuota = " + cuota);

        
    }

}
```

y si ejecutamos esto nos muestra por la consola lo siguiente

```
nombre = null
sueldo = 0.0
¿Cuál es su nombre?
Pepe
¿Cuál es su sueldo?
65000
nombre = Pepe
sueldo = 65000.0
cuota = 2600.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

Y eso sería todo. Espero que te sea ilustrativo y te haya ayudado a resolver tus dudas y entender mejor el manejo de una clase, en el punto en el que te encuentras.

Answer (score 0):

En cuanto a calcular la cuota Infonavit lo veo correcto, pero para que se realice correctamente el calculo solo debes crear una instancia del objeto empleado y modificar el valor de sus propiedades mediante los "setter" obtener el valor de sus propiedades mediante los "getter"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here  
        Scanner tec = new Scanner (System.in);
        Empleado employee= new Empleado();
       // Empleado sueldoo= new Empleado();
        //Empleado calcCuota= new Empleado();
        
        System.out.println("¿Cuál es su nombre");
        String nombre = tec.nextLine();
        employee.setNombre(nombre);   

        System.out.println("Indique su sueldo");
        float sueldo = tec.nextFloat();
         employee.setSueldo(sueldo);              
        
         
       System.out.println("El nombre del empleado es " + employee.getNombre());
       System.out.println("El sueldo del empleado es " + employee.getSueldo());
       System.out.println("La cuota Infonavit es " + employee.calcCuotaInfonavit());


    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que no tienes claro ciertos conceptos de la PROGRAMACIÓN ORIENTADA A OBJETOS (POO), sería bueno que revisaras los enlaces que dejo en la respuesta:

**CLASE EMPLEADO**
Los atributos de clase deben cumplir con uno de los pilares de la **POO** que es la [ENCAPSULACIÓN](https://blogsaverroes.juntadeandalucia.es/apuntesprogramacion/2018/07/05/el-encapsulamiento-y-la-visibilidad-en-java/), por ello deben ser de tipo **private**.

```
private String nombre;
private float sueldo;
```

No es necesario usar una variable local en el método `calcCuotaInfonavit` porque el calculo del valor que va retornar se puede hallar de forma directa.

```
public float calcCuotaInfonavit(){
     return 0.04f*sueldo;        
}
```

**CLASE ADMINISTRADOR**
El operador [new](http://profesores.fi-b.unam.mx/carlos/java/java_basico4_2.html#:%7E:text=El%20operador%20new%20regresa%20una%20referencia%20a%20un%20nuevo%20objeto.&text=Un%20constructor%20es%20un%20tipo,un%20objeto%20de%20una%20clase.), lo que realiza es crear una instancia de la clase.

> Empleado employee= new Empleado();
> Empleado sueldoo= new Empleado();
> Empleado calcCuota= new Empleado();

Lo que estas haciendo en las líneas de arriba es crear 3 objetos (employee, sueldoo, calcCuota) de la clase `Empleado` para poder acceder a sus atributos y métodos.

La clase Empleado quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Administrador {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here  
        Scanner tec = new Scanner (System.in);  
        
        //1. Crear un objeto de la clase Empleado.
            Empleado employee= new Empleado();
            
        //2. Leer el nombre del empleado.
            System.out.println("¿Cuál es su nombre");
            String nombre = tec.nextLine();
        
        //3. Leer el sueldo del empleado.
            System.out.println("Indique su sueldo");
            float sueldo = tec.nextFloat();
            
        //4. Asignar el nombre del empleado.
            employee.setNombre(nombre);
            
        //5. Asignar el sueldo del empleado.
            employee.setSueldo(sueldo);
            
        //6. Determinar la cuota de INFONAVIT del empleado.
            //Esto se halla automaticamente en el método calcCuotaInfonavit de la
            // clase Empleado al realizar el paso 5 
            
        //7. Mostrar el nombre del empleado.
            System.out.println("Nombre: "+employee.getNombre());            
        
        //8. Mostrar el sueldo del empleado.
            System.out.println("Sueldo: "+employee.getSueldo());
            
        //9. Mostrar la cuota de INFONAVIT del empleado.
            System.out.println("Cuota INFONAVIT: "+employee.calcCuotaInfonavit());
    } 
}
```