# Como puedo guardar datos en un array en Java

Tags: java, array, arraylist, intellij-idea

estoy empezando con esto de la programación con Java y en una parte de un ejercicio me he atascado, tengo una clase Paciente y dos métodos, un método me pedirá todos los datos del paciente y los tiene que almacenar en un array para que así el otro método lo muestre, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? ¿Es necesario para poder almacenarlos utilizar Getters y Setters o hay alguna otra manera? EDIT: Acabo de pasar todo a privado, quizás así es más fácil, aún así sigo sin saber como puedo mostrar los datos en el método MostrarDatos(); Tampoco sé si lo que he hecho está bien

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Paciente {
private float alturaCuadrado;
private int x = 0;
private int contador = 0;
private String nombre = null;
private int n_pacientes = 0;
private int edad = 0;
private double peso;
private float altura;
private double imc;

public float getAlturaCuadrado() {return alturaCuadrado;}
public int getX() { return x; }
public int getContador() {return contador;}
public String getNombre() {return nombre;}
public int getN_pacientes() {return n_pacientes;}
public int getEdad () {return edad;}
public double getPeso () {return peso;}
public float getAltura () {return altura;}
public double getImc() { return imc;}


public void setAlturaCuadrado(float alturaCuadrado) 
{this.alturaCuadrado = alturaCuadrado;}
public void setX (int x) { this.x = x; }
public void setContador(int contador) {this.contador = 
contador;}
public void setNombre (String nombre) {this.nombre = nombre;}
public void setN_pacientes(int n_pacientes) {this.n_pacientes = 
n_pacientes;}
public void setEdad(int edad) {this.edad = edad;}
public void setPeso(double peso) {this.peso = peso;}
public void setAltura(float altura) {this.altura = altura;}
public void setImc(double imc) {this.imc = imc;}

public void obtenerDatos() {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("¿Cuantos pacientes quieres 
 introducir?");
     n_pacientes = teclado.nextInt();
     Paciente pacientes [] = new Paciente [n_pacientes];


    for (int i = 0; i < n_pacientes;i++ ) {
        pacientes [i] = new Paciente();
        System.out.println("¿Cual es tu nombre?");
        nombre = teclado.next();
        pacientes[i].setNombre(nombre);
        System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu edad?");
        edad = teclado.nextInt();
        pacientes[i].setEdad(edad);
        System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu peso?");
        peso = teclado.nextDouble();
        pacientes[i].setPeso(peso);
        System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu altura? (En metros)");
        altura = teclado.nextFloat();
        pacientes[i].setAltura(altura);

    }
}


public void mostrarDatos() {
    for (int j = 0; j < n_pacientes; j++) {
        System.out.println(pacientes[j].getPeso());

    }


}
```

Comment: los métodos obtenerDatos y mostrarDatos deberías estar en otra clase; la clase Paciente debe tener los Getters y Setters

Comment: LA clase Paciente agregala completamente por favor

Comment: Talvez esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/492343/193364) puede ayudarte a despejar porque debes usar  **encapsulamiento** en los atributos

Comment: @Joshin en el ejercicio me obligan a poner los métodos en esta clase, al igual que declarar los atributos en esta.

Comment: @Elenasys he puesto solo el trozo de la clase paciente donde tengo duda que es en el tema de como ir guardando los datos en el array y luego poder recorrerlo para visualizar por pantalla todos los datos de los distintos pacientes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En base a lo que indicas con los nuevos datos, te comento como se podría hacer obviamente esto podría variar según en que parte de la teoría te encuentres.
Por ende esta respuesta estaría basada en las cosas que mostraste en la pregunta.

Primero, tendríamos la Clase `Paciente` en esta tendremos los siguientes datos.

```
public class Paciente {

private String nombre;
private int edad;
private double peso;
private float altura;

public Paciente() {
}

public Paciente(String nombre, int edad, double peso, float altura) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.altura = altura;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public double getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

public void setPeso(double peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
}

public float getAltura() {
    return altura;
}

public void setAltura(float altura) {
    this.altura = altura;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Paciente{" + "nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad + ", peso=" + peso + ", altura=" + altura + '}';
}
```

Los otros 2 métodos podrían ir en esta misma clase , en tu clase principal o en tu clase de servicio ( por eso preguntaba en que parte de la teoría vas) , pero podria ser asi.

```
public void obtenerDatos() {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
    System.out.println("Cuanto pacientes ingresara");
    int n_pacientes = teclado.nextInt();
    Paciente pacientes[]= new Paciente[n_pacientes];
    Paciente p=null;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_pacientes; i++) {
    
    System.out.println("¿Cual es tu nombre?");
    var nombre = teclado.next();
    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu edad?");
    var edad = teclado.nextInt();
    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu peso?");
    var peso = teclado.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("¿Cuál es tu altura? (En metros)");
    var altura = teclado.nextFloat();
    p = new Paciente(nombre, edad, peso, altura);  
    pacientes[i]=p;
    }
    //este seria el for para mostrar los datos, se puede poner acá mismo o en otro método. 
    for (int i = 0; i < n_pacientes; i++) {
        System.out.println(pacientes[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Haciendo lo que tu dices me saldrá, nombre, edad, peso, etc?

Comment: Con ese for tu puedes mostrar lo que tiene el vector almacenado, mi duda ahora que agregaste mas datos, en que parte de java vas? onda ya estas con herencia o recién en POO ?

Comment: Al hacer el paciente[i] lo que haces es obtener todos los pacientes que haya con sus atributos, el Paciente 1(nombre,edad,etc), Paciente 2(atributos..)

Comment: Igualmente siendo tú modificaría la forma de escribir código puesto que en la definición de la creación de la clase Paciente estás metiendo métodos como mostrarDatos, que deberían de ir en otra clase distinta

Comment: @Folkvangr Estoy comenzando, la práctica consiste en utilizar y practicar con los arrays pero claro, en el método MostrarDatos conforme lo he hecho yo me da error y no sé como hacerlo.

Comment: @RoyalUp Si en el método mostrarDatos() hago esto:                                                           public void mostrarDatos() {

        for (int j = 0; j < n_pacientes; j++) {
            System.out.println(pacientes[i]);

        }                         /* Me da error diciendome que no se puede resolver el simbolo pacientes ni el simbolo i  */

Comment: @starnix si puedes revisa el código que edite recién.